# Node.js with firebase does not save info in the Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, session, cookies

I am trying to use session in my app, to keep track on user log-in and more.

But...

When I tried using the simplest way, I kept getting the error :

> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale past a single process.

There for, after much searching, I added the firebase-session functionality, 
but now, even though I get no error, nothing is saved in the session.

This is my code:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const express = require('express');
    const session = require('express-session');
    const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(session);
    const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

    const ref = firebase.initializeApp(
        functions.config().firebase
    );

    const app = express();

    app.use(session({
      store: new FirebaseStore({
        database: ref.database()
      }),
      secret: 'asdfasgbrwewet53hnhwetynsy',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true
    }));

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.session);
      req.session.username='rakafa';
      res.send('Returning with some text');
    });

    app.get('/bar', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req.session);
      var someAttribute = req.session.username;
      res.send(`This will print the attribute I set earlier: ${someAttribute}`);
    });


    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is what I did so far:

- My original example taht I used to start using session: [session-express example](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/)
- I took the firebase part from npm: [npm firebase-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-session-firebase)
- Tried to use radis-store as a solution, didn't word: [using radis-store solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882535/warning-connect-session-memorystore-is-not-designed-for-a-production-environm/44884800#44884800)
- Using session-store, gave me the same worning as using nothing.. [npm session-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sessionstore)
- This question gave me the idea of using firebase-session [database sessions explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897276/what-is-the-difference-between-a-session-store-and-database)
- I saw this an example with cookies, but didn't understand, and didn't find another example [cookie session](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html)

Just another word, I only just started learning Node.js, so please try using simple examples, so I would understand ;)

And please forgive my starte's mistakes

**Please, HELP....**

=== edit ===

According to orxelm's answer, I changed my `ref` to this:

```
    const ref = firebase.initializeApp({
      //admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
      credential: firebase.credential.applicationDefault(),
      databaseURL: "https://*****.firebaseio.com/"
    });
```

But still, when I run the app, there is nothing in the session once I refresh the page.

[sessions in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLR56.jpg)
^^
I can see that the app created a lot of sessions in the server. 
but none of them have the information I added on the app, 
and since I use only one browser, there should only one session, am I wrong?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, when I was using firebase hosting and functions, but can be solved by simply setting `name:"__session"` in the session.

```
app.use(session({
  name:"__session,
  ...
```

after adding this, saving values in the session like `req.session.username='rakafa'` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where is you firebase config?
Maybe try to initialize the firebase admin this way:

```
 admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
 });
```

Comment: this way worked for me to get data from the database, but I will try what you say. 
Just, where can I find the credentials?

Comment: and where does "admin" come from? is it the same as my use of "firebase"?